# Excel 2010 setting up Table Lookup with 3 variables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

My Excel skills are a little rusty and I was trying to assign scores in a table based on the value of 3 variables (Var) in Excel 2010. I put an example below. The idea is the higher score of Var 1 and Var 2 are better. I also want to add a third value which is an alphanumeric and they are different but essentially of equal value. Here is a table and in the last 2 columns I have put in scores that I would assign the value in this table. If the values don't fall into the assigned ranges I would assign an N/A. Any help anyone can give me would be greatly appreciated in coming up with a formula. Thanks! -- Steve

For example here are 3 scenarios and the score I would want to come out.

```
Var 1 = 108, Var 2 = 0.5, Var3 = Red, Score = 3
Var 1 = 117, Var 2 = 1.7, Var 3 = Yellow, Score =  8
Var 1 = 98, Var 2 = 2.0, Var 3 = Red, Score = N/A

                                                                Scores  Scores
Var 1 >=    Var 1 <     Var 2 >=    Var 2 <       Var 3        Red      Yellow

100         105         1           2           Red or  Yellow  1       2
105         110         0           1           Red or  Yellow  3       4
110         115         1           2           Red or  Yellow  5       6
115         120         1           2           Red or  Yellow  7       8
100         105         2           3           Red or  Yellow  9       10
105         110         2           3           Red or  Yellow  11      12
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the columns `Var 1 <` and `Var 2 <` *such as `=B2&D2`* for the demo, I overwrote the Var3 column, as it's not needed for this, as the Var3 in the **vlookup** will define which score column to use.

sort this new column to be in ascending order

New Spreadsheet:

```
Var1 >=|Var 1 < |Var 2 >= |Var 2 < |Var 3 |Red |Yellow  
100     105      1            2     1052    1   2  
100     105      2            3     1053    9   10  
105     110      0            1     1101    3   4  
105     110      2            3     1103    11  12  
110     115      1            2     1152    5   6  
115     120      1            2     1202    7   8
```

now use `vlookup` on your result
`=VLOOKUP(VAR1&VAR2,$E$2:$G$20,if(Var3='Red',2,3),TRUE)`

you will have to create a no-score value, as it will look for the largest value above the scores), and your 3rd example with the data given would find the first value in the table